# Websockets + SockJs: ConnectCallback not executing on client side when using stompclient

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp, sockjs

My issue is:

```
        $scope.socket = new SockJS("ws/ws"); 
        $scope.stompClient = Stomp.over($scope.socket); // Connect to
        $scope.stompClient.connect("test", "test", connectCallback, errorCallback);


        function connectCallback () {
        $scope.stompClient.subscribe('/testurl',someFunc());
        }
```

Here my `connectCallback` method is not executing when connect is called. Neither `errorCallback` is executed. It just skips over this line although the socket is opened but I further want to subscribe inside `connectCallback` definition.

Can u suggest what issue it can be?

Comment: I have a example with PHP, RabbitMQ, STOMP plugin for RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I try RabbitMQ with plugin STOMP

https://gist.github.com/tineo/f4e1f977d78d0db438c8

and i use a PHP for create queues, channels, exchanges

https://gist.github.com/tineo/9b25444fa5095f2ef225

Maybe you can reuse my files with Spring.